# Changing <h1> color - Designfolio WP Theme. Google Fonts?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

I'm trying to change my `<h1>` & `<h3>` font colors from `#6b5d38` to `#253944.`

I've gone through all the stylesheets and searched for `#6b5d38` but can't find it anywhere? Bizarre!

The font color is confirmed through inspecting the h1 tag within Chrome.

I've just adding in `color:#253944;` to my `h1` within my stylesheet (currently doesn't mention color) but no change occured.

If I go to >Dashboard>Theme Options>Design Folio Options there is a Google Fonts section & Custom CSS section again I've tried adding in `h1 {color:#253944;}` to both sections but no change occured.

Has anyone had a similar issue which they've since resolved?

Thanks,

Sam

P.S.
My site link is:

```
http://79.170.44.145/sweetfe2.co.uk/
```

Comment: Maybe it's defined as rgb?

Comment: Check my answer you have mentioned color in your default.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below url

```
 http://79.170.44.145/sweetfe2.co.uk/wp-content/themes/designfolio-pro/includes/css/color_schemes/default.css?ver=3.8.1
```

You have a file named default.css where you have mentioned the `H1`, `H3` color

```
th, a:link, a:visited, h1, h2, h3, .site-title, .page-title, .entry-title, .nivo-caption a, footer .pc_info_widget .phone, #container .pc_info_widget .phone, .comment-author {
color: #6b5d38;
}
```

Changing this helps in changing color

To more understanding you can check the image..!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's defined in default.css (which could be dynamically built). Simple:

```
h1.entry-title {
    color: #253944;
}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try this

Style.css

```
.entry-title {
color: #253944;
font-size: 34px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 40px;
margin: 0 0 15px;
padding: 2px 0 0;
```

}